# Creating a TTree with Branches in Using Root through Python

Tags: python, root-framework, pyroot

I am trying to create a tree with branches in root through python. I have a .root file and I am trying to create branches that are the variables (or data pts) of my .root file. Here is my attempt:

```
f = ROOT.TFile('event.root', 'read') #opening the file and creating a file object f
T = ROOT.TTree("T", "simple tree")



#ntuple = ROOT.TNtuple("ntuple","Demo ntuple","px:py:pz:m")
T.Scan("px:py:pz:m")
```

This just gives me:

```
Error in TTreeFormula::Compile: Bad numerical expression : “px”
Error in TTreeFormula::Compile: Bad numerical expression : “py”
Error in TTreeFormula::Compile: Bad numerical expression : “pz”
Error in TTreeFormula::Compile: Bad numerical expression : “m”

Row * px * py * pz * m *
```

which I understand why since I did not define my variables. So I am looking through an example, https://www.niser.ac.in/sercehep2017/notes/RootTutorial_TTree.pdf, (slide 3) and I attempt to define my variable that should be contained in my .root file as:

```
f = ROOT.TFile('event.root', 'read') #opening the file and creating a file object f
T = ROOT.TTree("T", "simple tree")

px_as_floats = float(px)
py_as_float = float(py)
pz_as_float = float(pz)
m_as_float = float(m)
T.Branch("px",&px,"px/F")
T.Branch("py",&py,"py/F")
T.Branch("pz,&pz,"pz/F")
T.Branch("m",&m,"m/F")
```

But, I end up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
File “/mnt/c/1/writeroot.py”, line 17
T.Branch(“px”,&px,“px/F”)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to write this in python? Writing:

```
T.ROOT.Branch(“px”,&px,“px/F”)
```

did not work either.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/c/1/writeroot.py", line 17
  T.ROOT.Branch("pt1",&pt1,"pt/F")
                    ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix the syntax.
Ultimately I am trying to load the dictionary used from the .root file to my tree and then do some calculations on the items in the dictionary.
In other words, how do you extract the dictionary from the .root file?

When I type:

When I type gFile->ls(), I get

TFile** rdata.root
TFile* rdata.root
KEY: TH1F mass;1 masses
KEY: TNtuple tnt;1 tnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are trying to make bitwise AND operation, the symobl & is not valid. I assume that you want to send pointer to original variable.
We don't do this in python. If that's the case look up on google for local and global variable.
Tl;dr in python all mutable types are passed by reference 
Personally I would have wrote this like:

```
T.Branch("px",px,"px/F")
T.Branch("py",py,"py/F")
T.Branch("pz", pz,"pz/F")
T.Branch("m",m,"m/F")
```

Comment: Thank you. But after writing your suggestion I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/c/1/writeroot.py", line 13, in <module>
    px_as_floats = float(px)
NameError: name 'px' is not defined                                                                                 But px should be in the .root as a dictionary; why doesn't it recognize it?

Comment: Well it have to be in other part of the code, cuz I am not using this variable

Comment: That was a typo on my part..sorry. But I do still get the error. am I doing something wrong

Comment: How do you extract the dictionary from the .root file such that px is defined?